# Magento 2 : How to remove block from controller?

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers

I've been trying to remove block from controller.

I can able to render from controller but i need to remove existing layout block when new one render.

> Vendor\Module\Controller\Grouprequest.php

```
<?php 
 public function execute()
{
   $layout = $this->_view->loadLayout();
       $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Inchoo\Helloworld\Block\AcceptedGroupRequest')
            ->setTemplate('Inchoo_Helloworld::acceptedGroupRequest.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
            $this->getResponse()->appendBody($block);
     }
```

Need to remove **grouprequest** block. Which is rendered when this controller executed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How could I append to content ?